# background video not working in mobile view why?

Tags: html, css

i am using a video as a background in mywebsite but its works fine in web and why not in mobile view????
here is my html css and java script code but background video works fine in web view but why not in mobile i tried using different browsers in mobile but its not working at all ???? 
here is the  script for background video

```js
<script>
            (function() {
  /**
   * Video element
   * @type {HTMLElement}
   */
  var video = document.getElementById("my-video");

  /**
   * Check if video can play, and play it
   */
  video.addEventListener( "canplay", function() {
    video.play();
  });
})();
    </script>
    
the css for background video is here
```

```css
    
    
html,
body,
div,
h1,
p,
a,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* =============================================================================
  HTML, BODY
============================================================================= */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Oxygen", sans-serif;
}
     

/* =============================================================================
  VIDEO
============================================================================= */

.video {
 position: fixed;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
    
    .content {
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 720px;
  text-align: center;
}

.content__heading {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: rgb(39,39,39);
  font-size: 44px;
}

.content__teaser {
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: rgb(89,89,89);
  font-size: 22px;
}

.content__cta {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 12px 48px;
  color: rgb(255,60,100);
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: solid 4px rgb(255,60,100);
}
```

```html
the html code 
<video id="my-video" class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"  width="300" height="150">
  <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 video. Here's a <a target="_blank" href="#">link</a> to download the video.</video>
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me here https://jsfiddle.net/zcjLr4gc/

Comment: its not working in mobile browser why ??